# CORS issue in Chrome 69.0.3497.100

Tags: google-chrome

Cannot work with firebase projects locally (I guess after Chrome auto-update). I guess it's not firebase related but Google services in general.

I get CORS error despite the fact I don't use it. CORS extension is disabled.

```
Error: https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=AIzaSyB2rVH5oURUwciXasOeGlTNW7Lye6naCn0: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have tested Safari and it works, so the issue is Chrome related

Comment: You're making a cross-origin request to `https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token`, so the browser is enforcing CORS policies. It's unclear why the API is responding with a different origin (https vs http), but the origin should match.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger the thing is that i haven't changed neither code (it works in Safari) neither Chrome settings / extensions

Comment: Whether you changed the code or not, the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value in the response should match the "Origin" value in the request. There is not enough information here to determine why the are different, but they need to match if you expect your application to work in Chrome.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I'm not making them myself, it's firebase-sdk that makes them, I don't make them myself. And as I said it works in safari without issue, and it was worked in chrome till last weekend. So I believe it's chrome related issue. and the only idea that comes to my mind is to re-install either older version or more recent, not stable and test. any other suggestions?

Comment: The server is responsible for the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header, not the client. This means that the API is responding with the "wrong" value. I cannot determine this for you. You should look at the request and response headers in Chrome and Safari and compare them. Something tells me that the "correct" origin is in the response headers when using Safari, or Safari does not enforce CORS at the protocol level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this topic, but as far as I understand Chrome restricted http stuff even more.

1. I couldn't use https://localhost:3000 as there was no https server
2. I run webpack server for my js code and I've found solution to set HTTPS=true environment variable and it will enable the https option in webpack dev server.

Chrome doesn't respect such SSL certificate, but if you click Advanced -> Proceed then everything works and I don't get CORS issue any longer.

It may be a better option to generate some SSL certificate that Chrome respects so that you don't have to click Advanced -> Proceed every time, but I'm good with this for now as I can continue working on my projects.